# How to replace a submodule with local folder contents?

Tags: git

In my local, I made a git repo out of an existing codebase, which (unbeknownst to me) contained a git repo within it. When this created some scary looking errors about HEAD being corrupt, I went and deleted the .git folder in the inner repo.

Now Bitbucket considers this folder a submodule that points to a repo that I can't access (since it's not mine). However, locally, `git submodule` does not recognise any submodules existing.

As naturally follows, any clean pull from this repo just contains an empty folder where the inner repo is.

What I want is to tell Bitbucket to forget about the submodule, and replace that with the folder contents I have in my local copy; effectively "merging" this phantom submodule into the parent repo.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried removing the submodule with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule or https://gist.github.com/myusuf3/7f645819ded92bda6677 (except the step where you delete the actual folder), then add the local folder to git? If `git submodule deinit` fails, try the second link which uses more low-level commands.